# measure length of $(0,1]$ by infinite disjoint union

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

> Let be $J:=\{(a,b]\mid a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$ the semiring of half open intervals and $L:J\to[0,\infty)$ assigns each interval $(a,b]$ its length by $L((a,b]):=b-a$. We already know that $L$ is $\sigma$-additive, i.e.
>
> if $\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}I_k\in J$ is a disjoint union and $ I_k\in J$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$, then $L\left(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}I_k\right)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}L(I_k)$.

If we plug in $L((1,2]\cup (3,4])$ then the expression is not well-defined.

If we plug in $L(((1,2]\cup (3,4])\cup ((2,3]\cup (4,5]))$ then we are lucky and although $((1,2]\cup (3,4]))\notin J$ and $((2,3]\cup (4,5])\notin J$ the expression is well-defined and yields $4$.

This is because we can find a rearrangement of the intervals such that they form $(1,5]\in J$. Now let's keep this in mind and go on to the infinite case.

---

Let's assume that we have found a set $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{m_n}I_{n,k}$, where $I_{n,k}\in J$ such that

$$(0,1]=(0,1]\cap\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{m_n}I_{n,k}=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{m_n}\left((0,1]\cap I_{n,k}\right).$$

In our lecture the professor concluded

$$
L((0,1])=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m_n}L((0,1]\cap I_{n,k})
$$
because of $\sigma$-additivity. Is this legit without any further reasoning?

---

What confuses me is that we don't know if all the unions $\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{m_n}\left((0,1]\cap I_{n,k}\right)$ are in the "correct" order i.e. if indeed $\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{m_n}\left((0,1]\cap I_{n,k}\right)\in J$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. If this is not the case then how can we apply $L$ and use its $\sigma$-additivity? It feels that one has to make sure that there always exists an ordering of all the intverals such that $\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{m_n}\left((0,1]\cap I_{n,k}\right)\in J$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. But maybe I am overthinking.

Any feedback on this is welcome!

Comment: Can you add the definition of $\sigma$ additivity for $L$?

Comment: @Math_Images_Only, see my edit.

Comment: Given your definition you do not need the $((0,1]\cap I_{n,k})$ to be ordered in any particular way. They are all in $J$ and the countable union of them is also in $J$ and so you can apply $\sigma$ additivity

Comment: @Math_Images_Only, then how do you justify the inner sum $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m_n}$? This looks like that they are grouped somehow.

Comment: Since the series is absolutely convergent I can group up the terms however I want